# How to request JWT Token from KeyCloak via Java/Kotlin API

Tags: java, kotlin, keycloak

What I want is a JWT-Token from my KeyCloak-Server in a Unit-Test to test my Rest-API

How can I retrieve the JWT-Token via Java-API???
I know there is "Installed Adapter" https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/master/adapters/oidc/installed/src/main/java/org/keycloak/adapters/installed/KeycloakInstalled.java

but this Adapter can only login via Browser or cmdline.

I'm looking for something like MyAdapter.login(username, password)

Answer (score 0):

Find below code that could be used for testing.

The code basically makes a call to the OIDC *token* endpoint to retrieve an access token.

It assumes that there is a user called *tester1* that can login in with a password only.

Additionaly a password is required for the client. But the client can also be configured to work without password.

```
// data for token request
MultiValueMap<String, String> params = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
params.add("grant_type", "password");
params.add("client_id", "yourclient");
params.add("username", "tester1");
params.add("password", "secret");

// construct token request (including authorization for client(
RequestEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> authRequest = RequestEntity
    .post(new URI("https://keycloak.domain.com/auth/realms/yourrealm/protocol/openid-connect/token"))
    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .header("Authorization", httpBasicAuthorization("yourclient", "secret-client-credential"))
    .body(params);

// execute request and test for success
TestRestTemplate restTemplate = new TestRestTemplate();
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(authRequest, String.class);
assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK, response.getStatusCode());
assertTrue(response.getHeaders().getContentType().isCompatibleWith(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

// extract access token (JWT) from response
JacksonJsonParser jsonParser = new JacksonJsonParser();
final String accessToken = jsonParser.parseMap(response.getBody()).get("access_token").toString();
```